# Xcode 7 workspace file could not be opened after installing cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, xcode7.1, xcode-workspace

I'm  working on a project where i need cocoapods . I have installed pods . But the new workspace file doesn't open , with the error '... workspace could not be opened' . I tried closing Xcode before installing pods . It doesn't help either .

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there is an error in installing cocoapods.
You can try following commands.

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install --verbose
```

This will remove your pod first from your directory. Then start it again by command **pod setup** and **pod install --verbose**
-- verbose will show you what exactly happening in backend.